# IAR EWARM gives error on everything in startup_stm32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, assembly, compiler, iar

I'm trying to compile a project for school, which all my fellow classmates have no trouble compiling. This assignment is nothing more than dragging already written source code and compiling an, already proven to be a working, program.
I have added the file startup_stm32f30x.s from ST Microelectronics website, as per instructions in my school assignment, and i have not modified it at all. When i hit Rebuild all IAR gives errors on basically everything assembler.

For example:

`AREA`, `SPACE`, `PROC` and `ENDP` gives Error[40] Bad Instruction.

`EXPORT  Reset_Handler [WEAK]` gives Error[0] Invalid syntax

`ALIGN` gives a rather verbose error called
Error[413]: 'ALIGN' is illegal. Use directive ALIGNROM or ALIGNRAM (the first parameter is raised to the power of 2, the second is a 32-bit fill value).

I am right at the start of the course, and i am not supposed to yet be able to handle, and/or find solutions beyond your ye olde "Gosh! I forgot to plug the cable in".

Does anyone have an idea of where to continue now? I will happily supply whatever more information is needed to understand my problem, but please be patient with me being a noob on these things!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @LeonHeller  May be it's not directly about electronics design, but I'll use some clemency for this one.  EE.SE is about the only stack where an IAR question can get answered.

Comment: But there are numerous software related questions on electronics.stackexchange.com so forgive me for thinking that this might be the place for my question :)
Out of curiosity @LeonHeller, were do you propose i take these kinds of questions in the future?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I had picked a `startup_stm32f30x.s` that wasn't for IAR EWARM.  It worked better upon finding another file named the same and trying with that.